# Nautilus - show folder size in List view?

Tags: nautilus, directory

In the List view in Nautilus, I can see datestamp, name, etc - but it would be great to add one more extra tab and make the size of everything contained in a folder visible at a glance as well.

Is there a command or a way to do so?

Comment: Add it to where?

Comment: Do you mean when looking at folders inside Unity's folder manager, or are you referring to the command line?  Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: I mean that when you open the window manager...you see specific things....type of folder/file. Date...etc...
I'd like "size" to be there too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way directly to do what you want to do - if I understand what you want properly - however you might be interested in using `baobab` (can be run from the command line, or from the Unity Dash - also known as Disk Usage Analyzer) when managing folder sizes.

Comment: Jim, disk Usage Analyzer is a good tool, but I miss the way total commander on Windows had an extra line and showed the size of a specific folder automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I get you - that's just a heavier tool than you might be aware of.  For really large directories (say, /home, or /usr) it can take minutes, or in some cases even hours, to calculate the size of everything inside the folder!  You need to actually index the whole drive and cache that information in order to be able to provide it instantly in a file manager, or you run the risk of constantly thrashing the drives just from looking around.

Comment: Yes, it takes time. MacOS does an awesome job of this, running a process in the background and caching the results. im migrating to linux full time and i really miss this feature.